# Java unexpected character parsing txt file

Tags: java, utf-8

I am trying to divide txt files into ArrayList of strings and so far it works, but first words in the file always starts with (int)'65279' and I can't even copy this character here. Also, in GUI it looks like second letter of word is missing but at the same time it works in console. Other words are as they should be. I am using UTF-8 format .txt files. How can I change format in netBeans and GUI made in this IDE?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The second part of your question is unclear - if removing the byte order mark (as per my answer) doesn't fix it, I'd suggest asking a new question specific to that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+FEFF is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It's used to indicate the character encoding/endianness (to you can easily tell the difference between big and little-endian UTF-16, for example).

If it's causing you a problem, the simplest thing is just to strip it:

```
if (text.startsWith("\ufeff")) {
    text = text.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: What's confusing me is the OP's statement that it's UTF-8 files while `FEFF` is a UTF-16 BOM (according to wikipedia UTF-8 has `EFBBBF`)...

Comment: @piet.t: The *character* is 0xFEFF, and that's what the Java code is correctly reading - that's how I interpret the OP's question. The *byte* representation in the file woudl be EF BB BF though.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks for the extra explanation.